# Problem with turn on source-map code on dev configuration

Tags: angular, typescript

Sorry I'm a begginner. I try to configure my app to just simple debug app on my machine in chrome, but my typescript code is not generated as source-map code. 
I run my app through 
**package.json**
script:
`ng serve --configuration=dev --source-map=true`

**angular.json**

```
"configurations": {
    "dev": {
                  "optimization": false,
                  "outputHashing": "none",
                  "sourceMap": true,
                  "extractCss": false,
                  "namedChunks": true,
                  "aot": false,
                  "extractLicenses": false,
                  "vendorChunk": true,
                  "buildOptimizer": false
    }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "./"
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: By default when we run our application with ng serve it generates the source map. Did you try with cmd + p and search your file name? ng serve <PROJEECT_NAME> should be enough

Comment: Did you mean ctrl + p on DevTools -> Sources? If there I look for it there are just css files

Comment: yes..just start typing the component name...You must be able to see then

Comment: Nope.. there is nothing